# Help understanding mathematical recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I came across this method browsing the web searching for recursive methods.
Believe me, I cant get its logic. Basically this method finds the amount of ciphers in a given number.

```
public int aantalCijfers(int n)
{
    if (n < 10)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((n > 9) && (n < 100))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return (aantalCijfers(n / 100) + 2);
    }
}
```

Let's make an example. Let's imagine we use 5000 as parameter, my conclusion would be as in the following steps:

1. 5000
2. 52
3. 2 (returned by the else-if statement since 52 is between 9 & 100)

But instead, it returns 4, and it works fine, while I was expecting it not to.
Can you please, if you figure out how it works, point the steps of how this method comes to the correct conclusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. :-) But first, please note that the function says `aantalCijfers(n/100) + 2`, *not* `aantalCijfers(n/100 + 2)`. I have a feeling that you may have misread that.

The base cases are 1 or 2 digits. For anything beyond that, divide by 100 (thus stripping away two digits), recalculate, and add 2 to the result.

Using 5000 as your example:

1. `digits(5000)`
2. `digits(50) + 2`
3. `2 + 2`
4. `4`

You can extend that even further. Let's, say, use 1000000.

1. `digits(1000000)`
2. `digits(10000) + 2`
3. `digits(100) + 2 + 2`
4. `digits(1) + 2 + 2 + 2`
5. `1 + 2 + 2 + 2`
6. `7`

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty straightforward

- a number up to a hundred (and greater than 9) has 2 digits.
- therefore dividing by a 100 adds 2 digits to your count.
- You call the function again and it checks the remainder, it then keeps on going until one of the exit conditions, up to 10 or 10 to 99

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
 aantalCijfers(5000)

 returns (aantalCijfers(50) which returns 2) + 2 = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaken in second step, it's f(50)+2, not 50+2.
and f(50) is the second if, which returns 2, So it's 2+2, which yields 4.